# Keep selected tab highlighted in menu using CSS

Tags: html, css

Due to new eBay rules coming into effect in June 2017, all listings are not allowed active content.

I have created a tab menu using html and CSS. I need to keep the selected tab highlighted using non active and preferably responsive CSS and HTML.

Usually I would use J.S to change an active ID which CSS can manipulate.

What I have so far:

```css
#menb {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #BC2400;
  color: white;
  font-weight:bold;  
  text-align: center;
  transition: .25s ease;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
}

#menu_area a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;      
}    

#menu_area a:hover {
    color: #ffbf01;
    text-decoration: none;       
}

#menu_area a:active {
    text-decoration: none;    
    color: #ffbf01;
}      
      
.tab-folder > .tab-content:target ~ .tab-content:last-child, .tab-folder > .tab-content {
    display: none;
}
.tab-folder > :last-child, .tab-folder > .tab-content:target {
    display: block;
}

#postage {
    font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    text-justify: distribute;
    color:red;
    font-size:12px;
}

#button {
    display: inline;
    text-decoration: none;    
    border: 1px solid #B7B7B7; 
    background: #F7F7F7 url(http://www.electrohero.com/ebay/images/tabbut.gif) repeat-x 0 0;    
    background-color:#FFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 130px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    /*margin: 0 auto;*/  
    margin-right:8px; /*distance between buttons*/    
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px; 
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;     
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;       
}

#button a:link a:visited a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #f5f5f5; 
    font-weight:bold;       
}​
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
  <link href="simple.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
  
<body style="margin:0px">  

  <p>Some text....</p>   
    
  <br /><br /> 
                                                
  <div id="menu_area">
      <button id="menb"><a href="#tab1">Menu 1</a></button>
      <button id="menb"><a href="#tab2">Menu 2</a></button>
      <button id="menb"><a href="#tab3">Menu 3</a></button>
      <button id="menb"><a href="#tab4">Menu 4</a></button>
  </div>      
  <div class="tab-folder">
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
    <p>Menu 2</p>
    </div>                             

    <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">
    <p>Menu 3</p>
    </div>  <!-- end view3 -->    

    <div id="tab4" class="tab-content"> <!-- tab - What's sent -->                         
    <p>Menu 4</p>
    </div>  <!-- end tab 4 -->    

    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content"> <!-- tab - Compatible Devices -->                                 
    <p>Menu 1</p>                                                                                       
    </div> <!-- end view1 --> 
  </div>   <!-- end tab-folder -->
    
  </body> 
</html>​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I get you right, you need to track an active state without JavaScript? This is indeed possible by abusing radio buttons. Look at the following code.

Basically, I changed the structure a bit and introduces labels with a for-attribute as well as a `<input type="radio" ... />` for each tab. Radio buttons which share the same name are restricted to only one active one at a time. The label has the ID of each radio button (`tab1_active` etc.) as `for` attribute which activates the input when clicked. Two things are important: I had to remove the `<a>` since it was only possible to click the label or the a (which resulted in the correct button highlighted OR the correct section active). Secondly, the radio buttons must be at the same level as the menu and the tab container to allow proper css selector usage. The rest is selector hacking like `input#tab1_active:checked ~ #menu_area .tab1-btn` (read: For an input with id tab1_active which is checked look for preceeding elements with an id of menu_area and select each child with a class of tab1-btn...).

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding-top: 10px;
  width: 150px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #BC2400;
  color: white;
  font-weight:bold;  
  text-align: center;
  transition: .25s ease;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 12px 12px 0 0;
}

#menu_area .button {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;   
    height: 45px;
}    

#menu_area .button:hover {
    color: #ffbf01;
    text-decoration: none;       
}

#menu_area .button:active {
    text-decoration: none;    
    color: #ffbf01;
}          

#postage {
    font-family:verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    text-align:center;
    text-justify: distribute;
    color:red;
    font-size:12px;
}

#button {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;    
    border: 1px solid #B7B7B7; 
    background: #F7F7F7 url(http://www.electrohero.com/ebay/images/tabbut.gif) repeat-x 0 0;    
    background-color:#FFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 8px; 
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px; 
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: 130px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color: #f5f5f5;
    /*margin: 0 auto;*/  
    margin-right:8px; /*distance between buttons*/    
    font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;     
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;     
    padding: 4px;
}

label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.tab-folder .tab-content {
  display: none;
}

input#tab1_active:checked ~ #menu_area .tab1-btn {
  color: #ffbf01!important;
}

input#tab1_active:checked ~ .tab-folder #tab1 {
  display: block;
}

input#tab2_active:checked ~ #menu_area .tab2-btn {
  color: #ffbf01!important;
}

input#tab2_active:checked ~ .tab-folder #tab2 {
  display: block;
}

input#tab3_active:checked ~ #menu_area .tab3-btn {
  color: #ffbf01!important;
}

input#tab3_active:checked ~ .tab-folder #tab3 {
  display: block;
}

input#tab4_active:checked ~ #menu_area .tab4-btn {
  color: #ffbf01!important;
}

input#tab4_active:checked ~ .tab-folder #tab4 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>  
  <link href="simple.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
  
<body style="margin:0px">  

  <p>Some text....</p>   
    
  <br /><br /> 
  
  <input type="radio" name="active-menu" id="tab1_active" checked>
  <input type="radio" name="active-menu" id="tab2_active">
  <input type="radio" name="active-menu" id="tab3_active">
  <input type="radio" name="active-menu" id="tab4_active">
 
  <div id="menu_area">   
      
        <label for="tab1_active">
              <div class="button menb tab1-btn">Menu 1</div>    
        </label> 
      
        <label for="tab2_active">
          <div class="button menb tab2-btn">Menu 2</div>
        </label>
            
        <label for="tab3_active">
          <div class="button menb tab3-btn">Menu 3</div>
        </label>   
        
        <label for="tab4_active">
         <div class="button menb tab4-btn"> Menu 4</div> 
        </label>
               
  </div>      
  <div class="tab-folder">
    <div id="tab2" class="tab-content">
    <p>Menu 2</p>
    </div>                             

    <div id="tab3" class="tab-content">
    <p>Menu 3</p>
    </div>  <!-- end view3 -->    

    <div id="tab4" class="tab-content"> <!-- tab - What's sent -->                         
    <p>Menu 4</p>
    </div>  <!-- end tab 4 -->    

    <div id="tab1" class="tab-content"> <!-- tab - Compatible Devices -->                                 
    <p>Menu 1</p>                                                                                       
    </div> <!-- end view1 --> 
  </div>   <!-- end tab-folder -->
    
  </body> 
</html>​
```

Comment: Thanks this works brilliantly in Chrome and Edge browsers only thing is a ? after the menus, not sure why... Also it refuses to change the menu in any version of IE. Is there anyway to remove the ? at the end and get it to work in IE?

Comment: @hrhsii I updated the snippet. It now works for me in all current major browsers: IE 11, Edge, Firefox, Chrome & Chrome Canary. Note that I removed the `<button>` elements in favor of a simple `<div>` with a class of `button`. Button elements are inputs, hence they may catch the click on the label. I don't see a ? in any browser, I may have removed/fixed it along the way.

Comment: Great! It is now working in IE. Still have a question mark (?) at the end after menu content, not sure why...

Comment: @hrhsii Thanks for accepting! Do you have the question mark within my snipped ("Run code snippet") or after you copied it to your code? I'm afraid I still don't see a question mark.

Comment: Code snippet does not show the question mark (?) Only when I copy the code and run it on a local machine. I tried two computers both have a question mark symbol.

I have just tried and the question mark has gone, very strange... Just interesting to know where it came from.

Comment: I checked on another computer and question mark was present after closing html tag. It must have been a file encoding issue, and nothing to do with the html/css code.

Comment: @hrhsii That's indeed possible if, for imstance, the charset in the `<meta name="charset">` dffers from the one the file was encoded with.